# Consume protected web service from Infopath form in SharePoint online (Office 365)

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, office365, infopath, sharepoint-online

we are trying to consume a protected internal web service from Infopath form by creating a Data connection, i am able create the connection as it prompts me to enter my windows credentials while creating the connection. However after publishing the form, when calling the webservice through a button action, i am getting a error, so i created a secure store with the credentials and added to UDC file. But now, i am getting this error. But, SharePoint online do not have the option for Infopath form services configuration.

"ULS Error :  Outer Exception: Authentication information in the UDC file could not be used for this connection because user forms are not allowed to use UDC authentication. "

is there a different way to consume the protected web service or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to [InfoPath Forms Services differences between SharePoint Online (DvNext/MT) and SharePoint On-Premises](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4017854/infopath-forms-services-differences-between-sharepoint-online-dvnext-m) this is not supported in SharePoint Online:

> When you use an InfoPath form in the browser through Office 365, **UDCX connections that contain explicit credentials or Secure Store Application details fail**. This is because of the following InfoPath Forms Services options that aren't enabled in the cloud:
>
> - Allow embedded SQL authentication
> - Allow user form templates to user authentication information that's contained in data connection files